# Solve the equation involving integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, definite-integrals

> Let $$f(x) = e^{-x} + 2\int_0^x e^{-3t}f(x-t)dt,$$ solve $f(x)$.

I tried to apply $u = x - t$ but it didn't help . Also using Leibniz integral rule leads to $$f'(x) = -e^{-x} + 2(e^{-3x} + \int_0^x e^{-3t}f'(x-t)dt)$$ and I'm stuck here .

Comment: @Nosrati No , I don't know .

Comment: You can apply partial integration to the last integral to restore the original form of the integral and get the ODE without substituting the integration variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After applying $u=x-t$ one obtains $$f(x)=e^{-x}+2e^{-3x}\int_0^xe^{3u}f(u)du.$$ Differentiating this equation gives $$f'(x)=-e^{-x}-6e^{-3x}\int_0^xe^{3u}f(u)du+2e^{-3x}\cdot e^{3x}f(x)du.$$
Using the first equation, this can be written as $$f'(x)=-e^{-x}-3(f(x)-e^{-x})+2f(x)$$
which leads to linear differential equation $$f'(x)+f(x)=2e^{-x}$$
whose solutions are $f(x)=(2x+C)e^{-x}$, $C\in\mathbb{R}$.

Inserting expression for $f(x)$ in the first equation and solving for $C$ gives only one possible solution which is $f(x)=(2x+1)e^{-x}$.

Comment: You could also go over $e^{3x}f(x)=e^{2x}+2\int_0^x e^{3u}f(u)du$ so that in the derivative of both sides the integral vanishes directly. Or read that as $F'(x)=e^{2x}+2F(x)$, $F(0)=0$, with $f(x)=e^{-3x}F'(x)$.

Comment: If $u = x - t$ then $du = -dt$ but you used $du = dt$ . Why that's true ?

Comment: @LutzL Can you explain more ?

Comment: I used $du=-dt$, but I also used the negative sign to change the limits of integration from $\int_x^0$ to $\int_0^x$.

Comment: When you changed $\int_x^0$ to $\int_0^x$ ?

Comment: Supstitution gives $\int_0^xe^{-3t}f(x-t)dt = \int_x^0e^{-3(x-u)}f(u)(-du) = \int_0^xe^{-3(x-u)}f(u)du=e^{-3x}\int_0^xe^{3u}f(u)du$.